# The Perfect Predator?

Tags: genetics, evolution, zoology, biomedical-engineering

I’m not a biology major or even studying it in any way so I apologize if this makes no sense.

I’m curious, if say the Jurassic Park team came up to you and asked you to genetically engineer the perfect predator, what characteristics would you give it?

And I guess by "perfect predator" I mean a predator that could consider any living thing prey? Sorry again if this doesn't make sense.

Besides the obvious “Super strength” or “Super speed” or things that make no sense at all like “laser eyes” of course.

I’m thinking things like a flexible spine that expands and contracts to increase its bound when it runs, like a cheetah or etc.

Feel free to include any features from extinct or even made up animals as long as its actually theoretically possible (again no laser eyes!!)

Like I said this is not for any research or anything, purely for my own curiosity so any thoughts are welcome. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Biologically, the notion of a "perfect predator" isn't well-defined, because it isn't clear what is being perfected.

Predators are just organisms that eat other organisms. What would it mean to be "perfect" at being a predator?  Would it mean:

- Fastest possible at chasing its prey? *But it just needs to be faster than the prey, if it even bothers to chase its prey. [Sea anemones are predators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sea_anemone).*
- Most exactly adapted to hunting a specific prey? *Are anteaters a near-perfect predator?*
- Deadliest possible poison? *But many effective predators don't bother with poison.*
- Using the minimum possible energy to catch its prey? *Are passive predators like [pitcher plants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pitcher_plant) nearly perfect?*
- Impossibly smarter than its prey? *But it doesn't need to be smart. See again the pitcher plant.*

Perhaps humans are the "perfect predators" because we've so dominated our prey that [most of them live and die entirely at our whim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intensive_animal_farming), to the degree that many of us are barely even aware of them until their flesh is delivered to our dinner plate.

I hope I've made my point here, that the notion of a perfect predator doesn't really make sense biologically. Mostly, I think it's just a narrative idea of "thing that people would find really scary if it was hunting them."